# Which Instagram API should I use to collect public data?

Tags: facebook, api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Does either the [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api) or the [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/) allow me to simply get any public user's posts/media programatically? Everywhere in the documentation it says "User data" but it feels like I can only get data of the user that got authenticated using the API. I've set up a Facebook dev account and currently spending 4th hour on calling both APIs without success. Can anyone who has used them help me clear this up?

Comment: No, you can not get data for just any user. Business Discovery API allows you to get basic meta data for other business or creator accounts though, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery

Comment: thanks for the comment. It's sad but I understand why they dont want to create an open API. For those who are forced to get data from Instagram - look for web scraping (primitive way)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, Instagram API Date 365, a tool I currently work for, may help you as an alternative to using Instagram Basic Display API or the Instagram Graph API because this API is created especially for scraping bulk data about posts and users.
You can get such post data as post content (text, language, list of hashtags, list of tagged users), owner ID, location ID,
engagement info, etc. Also, it is possible to download comments (selected or on a specific post) and replies to them.
You can view [this](https://data365.co/instagram) for more info.